# Advise to optimize the following code in a better way

Tags: c#, linq, unity-game-engine

I have some data stored in a dictionary where the values are basically a list of objects with few attributes in them. Right now I'm looping through as following to get the data stored in a specific attribute. These data are then added into a drop down list (unity UI dropdown)

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<NameIDValuePair>> kvp in TeamValuePair)
            {
                List<NameIDValuePair> list = kvp.Value;

                if(kvp.Key == teamNames.options[teamNames.value].text)
                {
                    foreach (var rec in list)
                    {
                        screenNamesDropDown.options.Add(new TMP_Dropdown.OptionData { text = rec.ScreenName });
                    }
                }
            }
```

teamNames and screenNamesDropDown are dropdown elements part of my unity UI.

The structure of the NameIdValuePair looks as follows:

```
public class NameIdValuePair 
        {
            public string ScreenName { get; private set; }

            public string ScreenId { get; private set; }
        }
```

I would like to optimize this piece of code in a better way using linq - so that it's a bit more readable. Since I'm pretty new to linq, i'm not really sure if I'm using the right keywords when searching for suggestions but so far I haven't had much success in finding any helpful suggestion.

Thanks

Comment: The best way to answer this is, post this on [Code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: LINQ is a great tool to filter or select collections, not to consume the resulting query. Your code just shows how you consume the result that you already have. So there is nothing to optimize with LINQ. In other words, LINQ could have helped to build that dictionary but it can't replace the `foreach` loop.

Comment: why you iterating dictionary `TeamValuePair`? key cannot be duplicated so code inside `if` is in fact executed once (if key exists) ... you may obtain list just using dictionarys indexer directly with given key (with assumption that key exists)

Comment: Instead of looping the dictionary try `TeamValuePair.TryGetValue(teamNames.options[teamNames.value].text, out var list)` to get the single list you need out or if there isn't an entry for the key then it will return false and you can skip it

Comment: LINQ is great for writing compact, expressive queries. But it relies on abstractions that has some overhead. So if performance is a problem it is rarely the best alternative. And in general, readability is often difficult to combine with optimization, highly optimized code can be just about impossible to understand without very detailed comments.

Comment: @JonasH true .. I guess optimal code would be written in assembly -> readability = 0 ^^

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thanks a lot for your comment. Although I'm consuming the results with the help of foreach loop in this case, I was wondering if there would be a better way to filter/select out my values and put them into a list using the ToList() and add them directly into my dropdown using the AddOptions property offered by Unity UI Dropdown which can consume a list of string. I used Linq to construct the dictionary in the first place but I thought I could use some filtering techniques within linq to extract out a list and add the resulting list into the dropdown directly.

Comment: @Selvin I understand that the key cannot be duplicated but in my case I would like to add the values into a new dropdown based on the value set in a different dropdown. Without the if condition, this piece of code will include all the resulting values into my dropdown.

Comment: @juharr I'll try it out and see how it works out for me :) Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @JonasH I understood after some reading and research that Linq is rarely the best alternative just like your comment but I was just learning linq and thought of playing around with it in this case to see if linq would be a better way to express this piece of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned before instead of looping a `Dictionary` - where we already know that the keys are unique - you could simply use [`Dictionary.TryGetValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.trygetvalue)

```
// do this only once! 
var key = teamNames.options[teamNames.value].text;

if (TeamValuePair.TryGetValue(key, out var list))
{
    foreach(var item in list)
    {
        screenNamesDropDown.options.Add(new TMP_Dropdown.OptionData(item.ScreenName));
    }
}
```

and then actually the only place where you could use Linq if you really want to would maybe be in

```
var key = teamNames.options[teamNames.value].text;

if (TeamValuePair.TryGetValue(key, out var list))
{
    screenNamesDropDown.options.AddRange(list.Select(item => new TMP_Dropdown.OptionData(item.ScreenName)));
}
```

if this makes it better to read is questionable though.

And in general the question would also be if you always want to `Add` (`AddRange`) to the `screenNamesDropDown.options` or if you maybe want to actually replace the options. Then instead of `AddRange` you could do

```
screenNamesDropDown.options = list.Select(item => new TMP_Dropdown.OptionData(item.ScreenName)).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I wanted to have linq included just to see if there would be a better way to filter/select out values & put them into a list using the ToList() and add them directly into my dropdown using the AddOptions property offered by Unity UI Dropdown, which can consume a list of string. I have two dropdowns in my case where the first one holds the name of all keys. And based on the key chosen in the first dropdown the screen names should be extracted and populated from the dictionary and included into the dropdown using the AddOptions function rather than using options.Add

Comment: I'll test your piece of code and will get back to you in sometime. Thanks again :)

Comment: Thanks. It was really helpful for me to restructure my code in a better way :)